# How to get an array of values from a json object in node js

Tags: arrays, node.js, json

I have a json object

> like this:
>   [{"value":148},{"value":433},{"value":448},{"value":463},{"value":479}]

I want to get an array of values from this object

> like this: [148,433,448,463,479]

So, how can I do this in node js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could:

```
[{"value":148},{"value":433},{"value":448},{"value":463},{"value":479}]
    .map(item => item.value)
```

See: [Array iteration methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const array = [{"value":148},{"value":433},{"value":448},{"value":463},{"value":479}];
const arrayOfNumbers = array.map(({value}) => value);

console.log(arrayOfNumbers);
```